# Why doesn't one element appear when doctype is set?

Tags: html

I'm trying to get a form going with elements centered...but that only works if I remove the `<!doctype html>` string. Here is a simplified example of the issue, I only see a green rectangle with `<!doctype html>` in, once I remove the declaration, I get a yellow rectangle vertically centered on top of the green rectangle:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-success d-flex align-items-center" style="width: 500px; height: 400px">
    <div class="bg-warning" style="width: 150; height: 100"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I may do something wrong here, but I'm not experienced with Bootstrap.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is related to doctype, as I get the same outcome either way. It's certainly not related to Bootstrap.

However, your width and height styles on the inner element don't have units. You're probably seeing some fluke where pixels are assumed in some scenarios. Put units on them and it works.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-success d-flex align-items-center" style="width: 500px; height: 400px">
    <div class="bg-warning" style="width: 150px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Having a look at things in your browser's document inspector would've cleared this up in a hurry. The style values were struck out in Chrome as invalid. You should be looking at that often as a front-end developer.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I'm using Safari and there is also a warning but very well hidden.